# Remove CSS set by tag name

Tags: css, tags, twitter-bootstrap

I have this:

```
input[type=button]{ a LOT of stuff } /* File 1 */
.btn {what I actually want to use} /* Twitter bootstrap */

<input type="button" class="btn">
```

But the input gets the style from the File1 instead of the TB. How to ignore the first styling?

**Edit for more explanation:** the class I want to add is from Twitter Bootstrap CSS. I don't want to change aaalll the places .btn and its variants (.btn-primary, .btn:hover, .btn-primary:hover), there are almost 200 and each with many items. Adding !important in each of those lines is what I want to avoid. I want to tell my html that the whole file is important.

**Edit #2:** Maaaaaaaaaybe I found the answer: http://thingsinjars.com/post/360/scoped-style/ Just maybe, because I'll test it now.

Answer (score 1):

CSS is hierarchical - keep in mind the most specifically defined rule is what gets used.

IE: if your button was inside a couple of divs, then you define the styles including the parent hierarchy, and because of being more specific, that is the rule which is applied.

```
.btn {
   // base rules
   width: 80px;
   color: black;
}

.parent .block .user-form .btn {
   // my rules defined here will override anything set in .btn, and also pick up the base styles
   width: 100px;

}
```

So, .btn inside .parent, .block etc will be 100px wide, but with the color black as defined in the base rule.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to danp's answer, ID will have greater precedence than class. For this reason you could try changing it to:

```
<input type="button" id="btn">

#btn {
/*css rules*/
}
```

Comment: Can't do that because btn is from twitter bootstrap and I want to use .btn in more than one button in the same page.

Answer (score 0):

Strenghthen the hierarchy. e.g:

```
div .btn {}

body .btn {}

.container .btn {}
```

etc.

Bear in mind, you will still have to overwrite any rules that have previously been set that you don't want at all though.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:
.btn { color: #ff0000 !important; }

Comment: !important is a 'last resort', to be used very, very sparingly, if ever.

Comment: I agree, but it will help define where the problem exists.  I don't recommend heading to production with this.  Thanks.

Comment: I thought about it. The problem is that .btn is inside twitter bootstrap css and there are more than 190 places where it's defines (.btn, .btn-primary, etc etc). I want to avoid changing this file.